# Secure WebSocket/Jetty server (not embedded)/HTTPS: Service unavailable (503)

Tags: java, ssl, websocket, jetty

I have a very simple WebSocket server from Danny Cowards' "Java WebSocket Programming book" that looks like this:

```
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;

@ServerEndpoint (value="/echo")
public class EchoServer
{
    @OnMessage
    public String echo (String incomingMessage)
    {
    return "I got this (" + incomingMessage + "), so I am sending it back!";
    }
}
```

I compiled it using gradle 2.7 (see `build.gradle` below)

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: "war"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
        compile 'javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api:1.1'
}
```

and placed it in the `webapps` directory of a plain (HTTP only) Jetty server (`jetty-distribution-9.3.6.v20151106`) and I could make it talk with the client that accessed the WebSocket interface like so:

```
            var wsUri = "ws://localhost:8080/echoserver/echo";
```

Then, I took the same `*.war` file, and placed it on a secure jetty server (running `jetty-9.1.3.v20140225`) but the deployment didn't work, and my access of the server using (note *`wss`* now)

```
            var wsUri = "wss://localhost:8443/echoserver/echo";
```

didn't work for an error. The specific error, from the JavaScript console on chrome, is `'WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:8443/echoserver/echo' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected Response code: 503'`. But I think it is because there was a RunTimeException scanning EchoServer.class that it happened (as evinced in the jetty `stderrout.log`):

```
2015-11-20 15:32:14.320:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.1.3.v20140225
2015-11-20 15:32:14.329:INFO:oejs.AbstractNCSARequestLog:main: Opened /opt/jetty/logs/2015_11_20.request.log
2015-11-20 15:32:14.329:INFO:oejs.AbstractNCSARequestLog:main: Opened /opt/jetty/logs/2015_11_20.request.log
2015-11-20 15:32:14.331:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:/opt/jetty/webapps/] at interval 1
2015-11-20 15:32:14.421:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanned 1 container path jars, 1 WEB-INF/lib jars, 1 WEB-INF/classes d
irs in 17ms for context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4c70fda8{/echoserver,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8443-echoserver.war-_echoserver-any-7817985
952118790015.dir/webapp/,STARTING}{/echoserver.war}
2015-11-20 15:32:14.421:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4c70fda8{/echoserver,file:/tmp/j
etty-0.0.0.0-8443-echoserver.war-_echoserver-any-7817985952118790015.dir/webapp/,STARTING}{/echoserver.war}
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file EchoServer.class
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:705)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:821)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:970)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:821)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My environment is a Ubuntu 14.04/x64/Oracle java 8. BTW, I downloaded Danny Cowards' source code from the website, and it is exactly the same code I have. However, it comes with its own mystery *.war (in the `dist` directory, but the ant build.xml is clearly referring to all manner of NetBeans dependencies which have no business being there, ergo I could not compile it using `ant`) and placed it in the HTTPS jetty and it runs exactly as expected, and I do not get an error when I access it using `wss:`, so it is not a SSL/self-signed-certificate issue, or so I think.

Can anyone tell me what might be the issue here? Any help with this is deeply appreciated.

Thanks,
Sonny.

PS: I have checked out a number of WebSocket/SSL/Jetty posts on SO, but they do not seem to address the problem I am having with Jetty.

Comment: I looked more in detail into the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)` and a number of folks are suggesting I go back to Java 7 (e.g.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092857/cglib-throws-an-illegalargumentexception-when-enhancing-the-java-util-date-class) !! This is an unsupported version of Java! Any workarounds for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetty 9.1.x is too old for JSR356 (javax.websocket) use.

Use Jetty 9.2.x or Jetty 9.3.x for JSR356 support.

Since you seem to be using Java 8, use version Jetty version `9.3.6.v20151106`.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to try this asap before I can accept your answer, but I am running into a LOT of trouble with keystore and SSL configuration for switching to SSL/HTTPS on 9.3.6. I looked at the Jetty website (http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html#configuring-sslcontextfactory) and followed it to the dot, but it does not help, starting Jetty results in `Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect` which I checked here again on SO, again unhelpful. I think Jetty documentation requires a lot of work; I hope to help.

Comment: Had to do `{jetty.home} $ java -cp lib/jetty-util-9.3.6.v20151106.jar org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Password "MyInterestingAndAwesomPassword"` and replace the `OBF..` lines in `{jetty.home}/etc/jetty-ssl-context.xml` and `wss` and HTTPS work now. Thanks!

Comment: Don't modify/delete/change/edit **any** files under `${jetty.home}`.  Setup your `${jetty.base}/start.ini` properly and just set the properties for your keystore there.

Comment: For those who are trying to figure out the new `jetty.base` related concepts, please see http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/quickstart-running-jetty.html#quickstart-starting-https